# facebook wall post images

Tags: html, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to post a status on the users wall using GRAPH API - https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/. But I have problem with the image associated with the post.

In my case, the picture URL looks like this :  https://images.XXXXXX.com/Images.aspx?imageId=???  , retrieves image based on request parameter . If I mention the URL as above I don't see the images displayed . Whereas if I mention the picture URL as a static URL (i.e. https://digitalpictures/test.gif), it works . Please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You could save the image from the picture URL as a file with a static URL, then delete it once it's been uploaded to Facebook.

Comment: Do able task , but might be a costly operation !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the https://images.XXXXXX.com/Images.aspx?imageId=??? can be seen by the facebook linter tool.  Use it as an og:image tag on a public url.  If facebook can't lint it, you can use it as the Picture URL in your graph API call.

Answer (score 0):

Add Open Graph tags to the GRAPH API request, specifically "og:image", "https://images.XXXXXX.com/Images.aspx?imageId=??" for your image.

Facebook Open Graph Protocol [1](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

Comment: You mean to set the picture URL as "<meta property="og:image" content="https://images.XXXXXX.com/Images.aspx?imageId=??" />  . It does not work , it as says invalid